# Display average value of parent values next to each sub value

Tags: mysql, sql

**[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6219f2/1)**

```
CREATE TABLE Campaigns (
    Campaign_ID VARCHAR(255),
    Campaign_Category VARCHAR(255),
    Sales_Volume VARCHAR(255),
    Sales_Quantity VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO Campaigns
(Campaign_ID, Campaign_Category, Sales_Volume, Sales_Quantity)
VALUES 
("C001", "Fashion", "500", "10"),
("C002", "Fashion", "100", "20"),
("C003", "Sport", "800", "15"),
("C004", "Sport", "300", "90"),
("C005", "Sport", "700", "80"),
("C006", "Shoes", "200", "100"),
("C007", "Shoes", "400", "50");
```

In the table I have different `campaigns` and corresponding `campaing_categories`. 
Now I want to get the `average_sales_price` per `Campaign_Category` and display this it next to each `Campaign_ID`. 
The expected result should look like this:

```
CampaingID     Campaign Category    average_sales_price
C001             Fashion                  20
C002             Fashion                  20
C003             Sport                    9.72
C004             Sport                    9.72
C005             Sport                    9.72
C006             Shoes                    4
C007             Shoes                    4
```

With the following query I only get the `average_sales_price` per `Campaign_ID`:

```
SELECT
Campaign_ID,
Campaign_Category,
SUM(Sales_Volume) / SUM(Sales_Quantity) AS Average_Sales_Price
FROM Campaigns
GROUP BY 1;
```

How do I have to modify my query to display the `average_sales_price` of the corresponding `Campaign_Category` next to each `Campaign_ID`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use correlated sub-query :

```
SELECT C.Campaign_ID, C.Campaign_Category,
       (SELECT SUM(CC.Sales_Volume) / SUM(CC.Sales_Quantity) 
        FROM Campaigns CC
        WHERE CC.Campaign_Category = C.Campaign_Category
       ) AS average_sales_price
FROM Campaigns C;
```

Here is [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6219f2/8).

Note : Do not use column position in `GROUP/ORDER BY` clause, if you change the column position in `SELECT` statement then query will fail to generate expected result. So, all qualify column name instead.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to want a "unit price" for the category, which you can calculate using window functions:

```
select CampaignID, Campaign_Category,
       (sum(Sales_Volume * Sales_Quantity) over (partition by Campaign_Category) /
       sum(Sales_Volume) over (partition by Campaign_Category)
      ) as average_sales_price
from campaigns;
```

EDIT:

In older versions of MySQL, this would typically use `GROUP BY` and `JOIN`:

```
select c.*,
       (total_vq / total_v) as average_sales_price
from campaigns c join
     (select cc.Campaign_Category, 
             sum(cc.Sales_Volume * cc.Sales_Quantity) as total_vq,
             sum(cc.Sales_Volume) as sum_v
      from campaigns cc
      group by cc.Campaign_Category
     ) cc
     on cc.Campaign_Category;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, the OVER clause is not available in mysql version. Is there any alternative solution?