# Get aggregated average values joining a second table and display them next to each value in first table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables which you can also find in the [**SQL fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0eef5/4):

```
CREATE TABLE Sales (
    Product_ID VARCHAR(255),
    Category_ID VARCHAR(255),
    Sales_Value VARCHAR(255),
    Sales_Quantity VARCHAR(255)
);
INSERT INTO Sales
(Product_ID, Category_ID, Sales_Value, Sales_Quantity)
VALUES 
("P001", "C001", "500", "200"),
("P002", "C001", "600", "100"),
("P003", "C002", "300", "250"),
("P004", "C002", "900", "400"),
("P005", "C002", "800", "600"),
("P006", "C003", "200", "150"),
("P007", "C003", "700", "550");


CREATE TABLE Categories (
    Category_ID VARCHAR(255),
    Category_Name VARCHAR(255)
);
INSERT INTO Categories
(Category_ID, Category_Name)
VALUES 
("C001", "Fashion"),
("C002", "Sport"),
("C003", "Shoes");
```

The first table contains the `Sales` for each product. 
The second table contains the `Categories`.

---

Now, I want to display all products and the `average_sales_price_per_category` next to each product. 
 The result should look like this:

```
Product_ID      Category      average_sales_price_per_category
P001             Fashion               3.66
P002             Fashion               3.66
P003             Sport                 1.60
P004             Sport                 1.60
P005             Sport                 1.60
P006             Shoes                 1.28
P007             Shoes                 1.28
```

I tried to go with the solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60436888/display-average-value-of-parent-values-next-to-each-sub-value/60436966#60436966) but I think the `OVER` clause is not available in my `MySQL` version:

```
SELECT 
s.Product_ID, 
c.Category_Name,
((SUM(s.Sales_Value * s.Sales_Quantity) over (partition BY c.Category_ID) /
SUM(s.Sales_Value) over (partition BY c.Category_ID)) as average_sales_price
FROM Sales s
JOIN Categories c ON c.Category_ID = s.Category_ID;
```

Error:

> check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'over (partition BY c.Category_ID) / SUM(s.Sales_Value) over (partition BY c.Cate' at line 4

What other SQL can I use to get the expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For *older* version, you can use correlated sub-query :

```
SELECT s.Product_ID, c.Category_Name,
       (SELECT SUM(SS.Sales_Value) / SUM(SS.Sales_Quantity)
        FROM Sales SS 
        WHERE SS.Category_ID = S.Category_ID
       ) AS average_sales_price
FROM Sales s JOIN 
     Categories c 
     ON c.Category_ID = s.Category_ID;
```

Here is [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0eef5/34).

Comment: Any idea for this as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60448750/get-aggregated-average-values-joining-three-tables-and-display-them-next-to-each

Comment: @Michi . . . You can apply same thing for that also.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `AVG()` here as an analytic function:

```
SELECT 
    s.Product_ID,
    c.Category_Name,
    AVG(s.Sales_Value * s.Sales_Quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY c.Category_ID) AS average_sales_price
FROM Sales s
INNER JOIN Categories c
    ON c.Category_ID = s.Category_ID;
```

The exact error you are having is coming from using `SUM()` in the denominator as an aggregate function, without using `GROUP BY`.  Another problem with what you were trying to do is that the total sum could be zero, which would lead to an error in your query.  Rather than trying to fix your current approach, you should use `AVG`.

### Demo

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for your answer. When I try it here http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0eef5/16 I still get an error.

Comment: @Michi That is because SQLFiddle is using the outdated MySQL 5.7 version, which does not support analytic functions.  [See this demo in MySQL 8](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=57dd4215b7e73cd9ca99288a1a0502fa) to see the query working.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the expected result using a subquery:

```
SELECT 
  s.Product_ID,
  ca.Category_Name,
  ROUND(average_sales_price, 2) as average_sales_price
FROM Sales s
JOIN (
  SELECT 
    c.Category_ID,
    c.Category_Name,
    AVG(s.Sales_Value / s.Sales_Quantity) as average_sales_price
  FROM Sales s
  JOIN Categories c ON c.Category_ID = s.Category_ID
  GROUP BY s.Category_ID 
) ca
ON ca.Category_ID = s.Category_ID
```

The derived table `ca` is an enriched `Category` table with sale price average for each category, so you can join this derived table instead of the original `Category`.